# get metadata while uploading image by cloudinary widget UI

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, google-cloud-functions, cloudinary

> Is it possible to get metadata of the image being uploaded by
>   cloudinary widget UI ?

**Present solution -**

1.uploading image by cloudinary widget UI.

2.sending request to cloud fucntion.

3.cloud function sending request to cloudinary to get meta data of the image by public id of the image.

4.recieving meta data at cloud function of the image by cloudinary.

5.sending minimal **required meta data** - **(A) date (B) location** to client side.

```
The whole process takes around 1-1.5 seconds.
```

*Most of the time consumed is the communication between cloud function & cloudinary to send request with public id to fecth metadata of the image and send back response to the cloud function. It take around around 0.5-1s depending on the size of the meta data.*

*Is there any better solution where i can get the metadata/exif (date & location of the image), on client side itself.*

*Does cloudinary while uploading through widget UI have any option of returning required metadata to the client.*

*Note - i don't have acess to input tag for image upload, as its imbeded inside cloudinary widget UI.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to set the `Image metadata` parameter on the upload preset you are using to `Yes` :

[image]

And if the image included location, it should be in upload response.